# Bootstrap Multiselect - How can i disable other multiselect(id=2 value=2),when i select (id=1 value=2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I want to disable other `multiselect('#multiselect2' option value=2)` having same options, When I select `Multiselect('#multiselect1' option value=2)` option `multiselect1` can select single and `multiselect2` too.

I've trying to implement `:onChange()` like in the following code. But it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#multiselect1').multiselects({
        maxHeight: 200,
        onChange:function(element, checked) {
            var brands = $('#multiselect1 option:selected');
            var select = brands.val();
            var selected = [];
            $(brands).each(function(index, brand){
                selected.push([$(this).val()]);
            });
            var brand = $('multiselect1 option:selected');
            var select = brand.val();
            $('multiselect2 option[value="' + select + '"]').
                prop('disabled', true).prop('selected', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: $('#your-select').multiSelect('refresh');
Try this after your last line

Comment: It works very well. I really appreciate it. Thanks, My Bro

Comment: You're most welcome bro ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#multiselect1').multiselects({
        maxHeight: 200,
        onChange:function(element, checked) {
            var brands = $('#multiselect1 option:selected');
            var select = brands.val();
            var selected = [];
            $(brands).each(function(index, brand){
                selected.push([$(this).val()]);
            });
            var brand = $('multiselect1 option:selected');
            var select = brand.val();
            $('multiselect2 option[value="' + select + '"]').prop('disabled', true).prop('selected', false);
            $('#multiselect2').multiSelect('refresh'); 
        }
    });
});
```

It will work.